# Automated periodic backup of Google Apps (email, docs, calendar)?

Tags: google-drive, backup

I'm a big fan of Google Docs for SME, having used it for two years in my current company, set it up for a startup project, and recommending it to folks starting a business.

While it takes away much of the pain and cost of providing these services locally, there is the nagging issue of not having a comprehensive 3rd party disaster recovery system in place.  This was highlighted to me by a recent blog post from [e1lven.com](http://e1ven.com) titled [Why no company that values their data should EVER “Go Google”](http://e1ven.com/2011/04/14/why-no-company-that-values-their-data-should-ever-go-google/).

Google has a couple of stop gap, partial measures *(like automatic forwarding of emails to another address)*.  But there does not seem any native-Google approach to backup Google Apps data.

#### Are there any automated periodic backup services for Google Apps data?

Comment: After reading this http://www.lastwordonnothing.com/2013/04/22/dumped-by-google/ your question become really topical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [backupify](http://www.backupify.com/personas) for online backups of gmail, flickr, twitter etc. There also appears to be a version for google apps(business version so you'll probably pay for it) but it's a great service and I've restored from it before.

Comment: Paying is OK.  This is business critical stuff!

Comment: This rocks.  Thanks for the answer.  Have signed up and am feeling much more secure.

Comment: Glad it works for you :)

Comment: Their security is questionable at best. They use their own security token to encrypt your data to Amazon cloud storage. That means that they can decrypt your data whenever they want. I have read that access to the encryption key is limited but you and I both know that companies security can easily be compromised, leaving your data in who-knows-who's hands. I can't see using the service for any mission-critical data etc. and I can't see using Google services for same. They need to offer the option for each business to retain their own encryption key that Backupify itself has no knowledge of.

Comment: If you are looking for an affordable on-premises backup solution, you can check CubeBackup.

Answer (score 0):

My Mac app, [CloudPull](http://www.goldenhillsoftware.com/), can back up your Google accounts. The app backs up Gmail, Google Contacts, Google Calendar, and Google Drive.

(Full disclosure: I am the developer of CloudPull.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [SysCloud](https://www.syscloud.com) G Suite backup to backup Drive, Gmail, Contacts, Calendar, and Sites. Works well for us. Restore is easy. When you first configure backup, you can schedule the backup frequency.